# Calculating the Shannon entropy

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, information-theory, entropy, chessboard

Recall that the Shannon entropy of a random variables X taking values in a finite
set S is given by
$H[X] = −\sum_{x∈S}Pr[X = x] \log_2 Pr[X = x].$
(We set $\log_2 0 = 0.)$ For a pair of random variables $(X, Y )$ taking values in the
finite set S × T, we write

$H[X | Y = y] = −\sum_{x∈S}Pr[X = x | Y = y] \log_2 Pr[X = x | Y = y]$
and

$H[X | Y ] = −\sum_{y∈T}Pr[Y = y]H[X | Y = y].$

Now, consider an 1024 × 1024 chess board. Suppose 1024 rooks are placed one after
another randomly at distinct locations on a 1024 × 1024 chess board so that no rook
attacks another: that is, the i-th rook (i = 1, 2, . . . , 1024) is placed at a location
chosen uniformly from among the available possibilities so that it does not attack
any of the previously placed rooks. Let $R_i$ be the row number of the i-th rook and
$C_i$ its column number. What is $H[R_{513}, C_{513} | R_1, R_2, . . . , R_{512}]$?

Using the above formula, we get

$H[R_{513}, C_{513} | R_1, R_2, . . . , R_{512}]=−\sum_{y∈T}Pr[R_1, R_2, . . . , R_{512} = y]H[R_{513}, C_{513} | R_1, R_2, . . . , R_{512} = y]$

No idea how to proceed form here/interpret what this means. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by first tackling the easier $H(R_2,C_2|R_1)$. First write (using fundamental properties of joint entropy)

$$
\begin{aligned}
H(R_2,C_2|R_1) &= H(R_2|R_1)+H(C_2|R_1,R_2)\newline
 & = H(R_2|R_1)+H(C_2)
\end{aligned}
$$
because $R_1, R_2$ do not impose any restriction in the selection of $C_2$.

Now, $H(R_2|R_1)=\sum_{r=1}^N\frac{1}{N}H(R_2|R_1=r)=\log_2(N-1)$, where $N=1024$. Also, $H(C_2)=H(C_1)+H(C_2|C_1)-H(C_1|C_2)$ (show it). $H(C_1|C_2)$ and $H(C_2|C_1)$ are computed similarly to $H(R_2|R_1)$ and are easily shown to be equal, therefore, $H(C_2)=H(C_1)=\log_2(N)$ and

$$
H(R_2,C_2|R_1) = \log_2(N-1)+\log_2(N)
$$